# Why is my request headers url different from requested url?

Tags: heroku, https, http-headers, cloudflare

I added a page rules to Cloudflare as recommended by this [article](https://medium.com/@sambecker/serving-a-heroku-app-with-a-root-domain-over-ssl-using-cloudflare-ce8fa5a2ee40) and updated my environment variable `API_URL` in my heroku app to remove the `www`

**Instructions**

> Forward all www traffic to your root URL by going to Cloudflare >
> mydomain.com > Page Rules and clicking Create Page Rule with the
> following values: If the URL matches [www.mydomain.com/](http://www.mydomain.com/)* Then the
> settings are Forwarding URL, 301-Permanent Redirect,
> https://exemple.com/$1

Now, when I navigate to my website I get an error and when I check the console in the network tab I see in the Headers a 301 status code but this is only on the client side.

I still see the url with `www` in the Request Headers and Reques URL even though I removed it everywhere.
Coult it be something cached by Cloudflare ?
What can I do to resolve this ?

**Edit:** I it is now working, I think the error was related to a persisting cache.

Comment: Sounds like there may be two issues here. First, does the site (non-www) load correctly?

For the Cloudflare page rule, all this does is simply return a 301 status code and a "location" HTTP response header value (which is the URL the browser will then load). In Chrome dev tools, can you verify on the request this is the case?

Comment: Yes the non-www website load correctly (both redirect to my heroku app). The response header shows the correct redirect URL

Comment: Think we need more details on the error described in your question then. You navigate to the (www) site, and the 301 status is returned, (with non-www) location in response header. But then an error is shown in your browser? What is the error?

Comment: The error was return by my react-query function useInfiniteQuery : 'Failed to fetch'.  Everything went back to normal few hours later so I suspect the problem was cache related.